# How to check sql query execution time in sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-sql-developer

I need to check any sql Statment exact execution time (how much time it will take to complete that sql Statment without running this query) in Oracle sql developer tools without running that sql Statment

Comment: What do you mean? The execution time is displayed by default.

Comment: Without running any sql Statment like select or   delete Statment,  I want to calculate time required to run select or delete Statment without running that query to find time required

Comment: The only way to get the time a query needs to run, is by running it.

Answer (score 0):

Getting exact execution time without actual execution, that just won't happen. The database is called Oracle, but it isn't able to predict the future.

But you can check the estimated execution time. This is a feature of the database, not SQL Developer. Use `explain plan for` on your query, such as:

```
explain plan for select * from dual;
```

Then

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

Result:

```
Plan hash value: 272002086

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The estimated time is in the `Time` column.

Comment: I never found that estimate in the `Time` column to be even _remotely_ accurate. I have seen queries with an estimate of hours complete is milliseconds and queries that were estimated to seconds run for hours.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get query execution time using Oracle sql developer tools. SQL developer is having option to provide the same.

Select the query statement and use F10 to get the estimated execution plan, please note that would be estimated only, not the actual plan.

Comment: Yes, I know this F10 option to check execution plan,  is this possible to get actual plan or time to complete any sql query

Comment: Without running query we cant get actual plan or time.